# IDE for XSLT and XMAP, XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a project which content a web folder, ajax folder, data folder ,xsl folder,xsl_provided, and two file with newproject.xpr and sitemap.xmap. I want to use a IDE to go through the project and run it. I'm new in XSLT,XMAP platform. Please help me.

Comment: What is XMAP ?   "sitemap.xmap"  looks like it could be a cocoon file. "newproject.xpr" looks like an Oxygen editor project file. What sort of project is this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Altova's XMLSpy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html). I've used it for working with XSLT files before and it works well. I don't know about the other stuff though.